# How to find a number from a string filed?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to extract a number from a text field.The tect field is not consistent.

I tried writing substring,but that does not work as the text is not consistent.

```
CASE WHEN position ( 'CNTRL ', ACTVY_NOTE_TXT) > 0 
            THEN  SUBSTRING ( ACTVY_NOTE_TXT,position ( 'RECORD ID   ', ACTVY_NOTE_TXT)+6, position ( ' [', ACTVY_NOTE_TXT) -  position ( 'RECORD ID   ', ACTVY_NOTE_TXT) -6)
        ELSE NULL END  as DisputeID,
```

#### Input

```
RCVD 2019-05-06 BOR DISPUTED VIA MAIL- - STATES VICTIM OF IDENTITY THEFT SENT 10030 LIDB LETTER -FRANK CHICK - 525 STELLAR CT 525 - KODAK TN 37764 - -STEP FAILED- CBR DISPUTE CODED IN LAST 6 MONTHS-C106 05 15 2019 13:33:42 MWZ    OPEN ACCT DISPUTE RECORD ID   999703 [PJR748:5 21 2019 12:00:00 AM]
```

The output should be

```
999703
```

Answer (score 0):

If our desired number always has a `[` on the right, we would use that in our expression:

```
([0-9]+)(?:\s+)?\[
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/sBt1PE/1/)

and our desired number is in this capturing group:

```
([0-9]+)
```

If it might always have 6 digits, we can update our expression with a quantifier:

```
([0-9]{6})(?:\s+)?\[
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/9paimi/1/)

If there is no other 6-digit number in our input string, we can simply use:

```
([0-9]{6})
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/fOQKlD/1/)

#### Implementation

For snowflake, if we wish to apply an expression, [this link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html) might be helpful.

Comment: A suitable regex is only part of the solution. How should OP code to use it?

Comment: hi thank you for the quick response.I need to use the regexp_substr function,...i tried using this regexp_substr(ACTVY_NOTE_TXT,'([0-9]{6})(?:\s+)?\['),its giving me an error "Invalid regular expression: '([0-9]{6})(?:s+)?[', no argument for repetition operator: ?" Any help is greatly appertiated.

Comment: HI @Emma,Thank you.Tried it but i have some other numbers int he field..so its giving me those numbers too.So i need get the numbers in front of the square bracket [.

Comment: @Emma.No luck.Tried this regexp_substr(NOTE_TXT,'([0-9]{6})\s\[')..Got an error Invalid regular expression: '([0-9]{6})s[', missing ]: [

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
\d+(?=\s*\[)
```

- `\d+` - Matches one or more digits
- `(?=\s*\[)` - Positive lookahead, match followed by `space` (optional) and `[` (must)

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Xz7sS2/1/)